# PHP OOP UNSET object from class in __construct

Tags: php, class, oop, unset, construct

I have some classes from which I create objects. In the __construct function I check the properties. If they do not match I would like to delete the created object.

```
$example = new example('Value 1', 2, false);


foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $propertie => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        // unset(); What i have to insert in unset() ?  
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [\_\_destruct in \_\_construct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593308/destruct-in-construct). This post details several options to do it the "right" way

Comment: You can't "cancel" object instantiation when you're inside `__construct()` function. Either raise an exception in constructor or create factory which will arrange all instantiation routines & dependencies for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset the created object.

Don't do this in your constructor, do it where you're creating the obj.

What you can do to centralize this code is to build a [Factory](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html). You could just tell that factory then that you want an obj of the type `example` with these properties set `val1, val2, val3...`.

Then the factory would run the code below and return the obj if everything is fine, if not you could give out an error message which explains what went wrong, like property wasn't set or something. Then you could react properly to it.

```
$example = new example('Value 1', 2, false);

foreach (get_object_vars($example) as $propertie => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        unset($exampe);
        break; //This stops the foreach
    }
}
```

Comment: The Foreach is in the constructor ... i cant access $example from that location

Comment: Ah, okay, wasn't clear to me in your Question. I'll update my answer